# How to cancel video streaming API request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Version: ASP.NET Core API 2.1.X working with IIS and windows server 2016

I am streaming a video from a URL to target:

```
public async Task <IActionResult> Get(string videoID, CancellationToken CT) 
  {
       HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
       CT.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       try
       {
            HttpResponseMessage httpRespond = await _client.GetAsync(oneVideo.Uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, CT);
            var _stream = await httpRespond.Content.ReadAsAsync<Stream>();
            return   File(_stream, "video/mp4");
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex) 
       {
        //Won't trigger when stream is canceled by user, Like close browser.
        //TODO: Cancel streams
       }

  }
```

I am receving the following error:

> System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: 'No MediaTypeFormatter
>   is available to read an object of type 'Stream' from content with
>   media type 'video/mp4'.'

Samples on the web are pretty insufficient or over complex for my usage.
I am out of options.

Comment: See [Using CancellationTokens in your MVC Actions](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/#usingcancellationtokensinyourmvcactions).

Comment: @MarkG I tried, but the Catch is not triggering. (See question update)

Comment: Try passing cancellation token using [GetAsync(String, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

Comment: @MarkG Thanks, I added `GetAsync`, however, i am receiving an error. Updated description of question.

Comment: Try changing action to return `IActionResult` and returning `File(_stream, "video/mp4")`.  Also use GetAsync overload that accepts `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to avoid preloading content.

Comment: Tried, still same error :( (see question update)